# How to change heroku billing account?

Tags: heroku, account, billing

I have a heroku app with several collaborators. I'm paying for a hobby server and postgresql db. The thing is I want the charges to start being charged to the credit card of a different account from a different collaborator of the project, who is now the owner (I transferred the app).
I was expecting that once I had transferred the app, it will start charging to the owner account but keeps charging to me.

I'm thinking of removing my credit card to see if with it start charging the owner account, but that will unverified my account and I'm worried about this messing up with the DB data and ending up losing something.

What can I do? thank you in advance!

Comment: Did you use the `apps:transfer` command, or the equivalent in the dashboard, to transfer the app? [Billing should change automatically](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/transferring-apps): "Billing responsibility will transfer to the new owner as of the time of accepting the transfer and the original owner will be responsible for pro-rated usage up until that point". If you remove your credit card and the app was not properly transferred your app may experience downtime.

Comment: Thank you @Chris for your reply! I transferred the app from the dashboard and the transfer was already accepted. So from what you are saying it should be automatic, I will wait a few more days to see if this regularizes itself. Thank you!

Comment: Note the second part of that quote: "the original owner will be responsible for pro-rated usage up until that point". You may just be seeing a final charge for whatever portion of the billing period occurred before the transfer.